# How to make entity framework (3.5) skip selection of identity value after insert?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have an entity mapped to a database table with an auto generated identity column.
After creating new entity and calling `SaveChanges()` EF performs an insert query which also retrieves the new identity value for the newly inserted record.

Sometimes I do not care what is the new value (for example, I insert a new log record and I don't really care about the identity value that was added).
Is there any way to make EF not querying for this value?

Thanks,
Itay

Answer (score 3):

EDMX file defines such autogenerated property with attribute `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"`. You have to modify EDMX directly and remove this attribute from both SSDL (and CSDL part probably as well). Changing the value from designer will only modify CSDL part which is not responsible for SQL generation. The problem is that after each update from database your SSDL will again contain this attribute because identity is defined in databse.

Edit:

The previous suggestion was theory. Actually I think it will not work because when you do not define the column in EDMX as identity it will send its actual value to database. In database it will raise exception because you will try to insert value to identity column without setting indentity insert on.

Comment: +1 Also, doing this might not be a good idea anyway - it means that the entity memory model is no longer consistent with the DB model (even if you promise to dispose of the entity as soon as it has been inserted)

Comment: Thanks, but as you stated it will probably throw exception while inserting.  So far the only solution I have in mind is to use Stored Procedure or custom SQL command.

Comment: @Itay: Why is it such a big problem for you? The identity value is selected in the same command batch as Insert command so the performance decrease here is small. There are much worse EF features (like lack of commands batching).

Comment: @LadislavMrnka We (my team) have a problem with this, the select (after the insert) to update the Entity PK value is blocking a page file (of that table); so other INSERTs will fail because the page file is locked. I'm still looking for a way to avoid this...